# Pandas - get first n-rows based on percentage

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I have a dataframe i want to pop certain number of records, instead on number I want to pass as a percentage value.

for example,

`df.head(n=10)`

Pops out first 10 records from data set. I want a small change instead of 10 records i want to pop **first** 5% of record from my data set.
How to do this in pandas.

I'm looking for a code like this,

`df.head(frac=0.05)`

Is there any simple way to get this?

Comment: are you looking for `df.sample(frac=*)`.

Comment: @shivsn- No I don't need sample. I want first n% rows. But i want similar fashion of df.sample to df.head

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I want to pop first 5% of record

There is no built-in method but you can do this:

You can `multiply` the total number of rows to your percent and use the result as parameter for `head` method.

```
n = 5
df.head(int(len(df)*(n/100)))
```

So if your dataframe contains `1000` rows and `n = 5%` you will get the first `50` rows.

Answer (score 3):

I've extended Mihai's answer for my usage and it may be useful to people out there.
The purpose is automated top-n records selection for time series sampling, so you're sure you're taking old records for training and recent records for testing.

```
# having 
# import pandas as pd 
# df = pd.DataFrame... 

def sample_first_prows(data, perc=0.7):
    import pandas as pd
    return data.head(int(len(data)*(perc)))

train = sample_first_prows(df)
test = df.iloc[max(train.index):]
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and @mihai's solution was useful. For my case I re-wrote to:-

```py
    percentage_to_take = 5/100
    rows = int(df.shape[0]*percentage_to_take)
    df.head(rows)
```

I presume for last percentage rows `df.tail(rows)` or `df.head(-rows)` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help:

```
tt  = tmp.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x)*0.05))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

With pandas 2.1 it is easier with quantile method in the example below we get first 10 percent and last 10 percent of data

```
 df.loc[
    (df['Column'] < df['Column'].quantile(.10)) |
    (df['Column'] > df['Column'].quantile(.90))
]
```

Comment: This however assumes that one column at least has numerical dtype, which OP has not specified.

Answer (score -3):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2))
print(df)
```

```
          0         1
0  0.375727 -1.297127
1 -0.676528  0.301175
2 -2.236334  0.154765
3 -0.127439  0.415495
4  1.399427 -1.244539
5 -0.884309 -0.108502
6 -0.884931  2.089305
7  0.075599  0.404521
8  1.836577 -0.762597
9  0.294883  0.540444
```

#70% of the Dataframe

```
part_70=df.sample(frac=0.7,random_state=10)
print(part_70)
```

```
          0         1
8  1.836577 -0.762597
2 -2.236334  0.154765
5 -0.884309 -0.108502
6 -0.884931  2.089305
3 -0.127439  0.415495
1 -0.676528  0.301175
0  0.375727 -1.297127
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but my requirement was taking top n% record. Sample returns random order rows.